# Execute process for n cpu cycles

Tags: linux, process, scheduling, proc, ps

How to execute a process for n cpu cycles on Linux? I have a batch processing system on a multi-core server and would like to ensure that each task gets exactle the same amount of cpu time. Once the cpu amount is consumed I would like to stop the process. So far I tried to do some thing with /proc/pid/stats utime and stime, but I did not succeed.

Comment: Attempting to do this manually (or via a script) is most likely going to result in all the jobs running slower than they could. You're better off just giving them all the same priority and letting the Linux kernel scheduler sort out the details. Unless you wrote the scheduler, chances that you can manually do a better job than it does are on the low-ish end...

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is impossible (to give the exact same number of cycles to several processes; a CPU cycle is often less than a nanosecond). You could execute a process for x CPU seconds. For that use [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) with `RLIMIT_CPU`

Your batch processor could also manage time itself, see [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html). You could use timers (see [timer_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) & [timerfd_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html)), have an [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) around [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), measure time with [clock_getttime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html)

I'm not sure it is useful to write your own [batch processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_processing) system. You could use the existing [batch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at) or [slurm](http://slurm.schedmd.com/) or [gnqs](http://gnqs.sourceforge.net/) (see also commercial products like [pbsworks](http://www.pbsworks.com), [lsf](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/platformcomputing/products/lsf/) ..)